# Firebase Database - Avoid downloading JSON repeatedly on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My use-case for Firebase is slightly different than most. We do not use FB exclusively for our back-end.  We have a large MariaDB server dealing with relations and all data.

Our goal with FB is to allow clients on iOS devices to have their specific data available.  We need to load the data once and then listen for changes to this particular data. Here is a rough overview of how it works:

1. The main ViewController is loaded
2. Firebase is initialized and we listen for FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded. (Persistence is enabled)
3. Firebase loads all matching records. We then loop through and store them locally in the internal SQLite DB.

In the normal userflow, we push other ViewControllers on the screen.  The problem is, once the main ViewController is loaded, FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded fires again for each record.

Questions:

1. When FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded fires again, is it loading the data from its internal cache (Persistence?) or is it re-downloading everything from the Firebase server? I've used Network Link Conditioner to completely cut the internet connection, and when I do, it does not fire the FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded at all, but as soon as the net comes back, it fires FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded for every single record.
2. How can I achieve the above where we load all records on login and then only listen for changes to those records? I am already using orderBy and startingAt so if the answer involves one of the above, I cannot add another "hasDownloaded=yes" filter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the code you're testing with. Without that it's hard to say anything concrete. See also on [creating an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The code doesn't matter in this case.  The problem is that there is no clear definition of how Firebase works behind the scenes.

For the sake of simplicity, I have a ChildAdded and ChildChanged listener in my main ViewController:

Please re-read my questions above as it pertains to understanding if the JSON is downloaded from the server every time the VC is loaded, or if it fetches it from its local cache but still fires the ChildAdded listener.

Comment: It's unclear what the use case is here without seeing how your viewController and Firebase is implemented in code. i.e. *every time the VC is loaded* is highly dependent on the code within the VC. The .childAdded event is intentionally designed to fire one for each child and then for any additional children that are added. It will fire for any new children that are added after reconnecting, however again, it's dependent on your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A Firebase reference listener connects to the server once, and stays connected until that query is turned off. As long as the reference being listened to is in memory, there is only one connection made to the database. Once this connection happens, all data will come through as child added data again.

The issue here is not so much with Firebase but that your app is continuously readding listeners to a reference, making the data be redownloaded from the network every time.

So to your first question, yes it is redownloading from the network. To your second, you just need to make sure the Firebase query never leaves memory. This can be done by making your query globally scopes, or simply by not turning off the query when the view controller exits scope (then you need to make sure not to readd multiple queries on subsequent loads).